# Pressing back button after viewing a PDF file, gives page expired error

Tags: wss-3.0, error, pdf

When we open a PDF in the browser from a document library, and then press the back button we get page expired.

One possible solution we have found is to open the PDF in adobe reader, as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174842/sharepoint-open-document-library-pdf-in-new-window).

Is their a way to solve this that does not involve changes to the registry on the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open the PDF inline in browser you get a "page expired" when you go back?

Where do you open the document from? Is it from inside a document library or from custom code?

I am asking this because getting a "page expired" is connected to doing a POST request (postback) and accessing from a document library is a GET request.

Caching can also be an issue, but again only in combination with a POST. You can examine what output cache profile you are using (an easy way to do this is by checking the Cache-Control header in the response header of the page using a program like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com)

Comment: Thanks, we were using a post to expand and colapse a document list